# Ajax call to Node.js server not working in qlikview extension

Tags: ajax, node.js, d3.js, qlikview

I have setup a Node.js server to render a simple d3 circle.

```
app.get('/circles',function(req, res) {
    res.render('circles');
});
```

The view engine is jade. Here is the jade template. I refer my java script libraries which are present in the public folder.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Enterprise dashboard
    h1 Welcome to Visualization
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/d3.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/d3circles.js')
  body(id='idofbody')
    div(id='circle')
    div(id='circle1')
```

When I access this from a browser, everything works fine. The d3 visualization works rendering the single circle.

I am trying to make ajax call to the '/circles' from a qlikview extension. But the page returned shows only the static part like h1 tag. The SVG that was made with the script in d3 call circles is not rendered.

The fire bug output shows this. As you can notice, the first GET is the call I made from qlikview extension. The second call is unexpected. When rendering the page, it makes a GET call to the script library  with a wrong url-url of the Origin. The url refers the origin and hence becomes unsuccesful I beleive.

note:I can't post the full output from firebug(with all GET calls) as screenshot due to lesser points in my side.

GET   http://25.25.80.63:8765/circles                        200 OK
    3.49s   QvAjax.js (line 23)

GET   http://25.25.80.63/javascripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js    404 Not Found       151ms   QvAjax.js (line 23)

But the problem occurs only within qlikview. When I do the same ajax call, from a page in a different node server, the script and css libraries are referred with the correct url - the url of the HOST.

Please suggest how to render D3 components into qlikview from the node server.